# Loan calculator with javascript and autofill input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a simple loan calculator to calculate the following formula

```
(AMMOUNT + (AMMOUNT * YEARS / PERCENTAGE COMMISSION)) / 12
```

Eg:

```
(25000 + (25000 * 10 / 5%)) / 12
```

The result needs to be `218,75`

I tried the following script example but I don't think I was able to implement the percentage commission correctly (DAE = "5%")

```
function calc() {
  var val = document.forms["calculator"];
  var DAE = "5%"; 
  var MONTHS = 12; //months of year

  if (val["AMMOUNT"].value != "" && val["YEARS"].value != "") { 
   val["RESULT"].value = (parseInt(val["AMMOUNT"].value) + (parseInt(val["AMMOUNT"].value) * DAE)) / parseInt(val["YEARS"].value) / MONTHS;
  }
}
```

Can you help me figure out how to get the desired result above?

Comment: you can multiply with 0.05 so DAE = 0.05

Comment: `"5%"` is a string, `0.05` as a number is generally used for percentage as an example. if it is a string originally, you may need to parse it out.

Comment: I tried with 0.05 but the result is now 25010.416666666668.

Comment: Look into the precedence of the math https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: Solved! I forgot to put some operators in parentheses. The updated formula: (25000 + (25000 * 10)) / 5% / 12

Comment: Sory, (25000 * 10 / 5%)) / 12

Comment: lol, still not your expecting result. I think you should either check your formula or your result.

Comment: @Alex trust me, it works :)

Comment: @Adrian can you do a snippet with it? I don't get 218

Comment: FYI I voted to close this due to the fact that your examples do not match your code `console.log((25000 + (25000 * 10 / 0.05)) / 12 )` returns `418750` AND does not match your code sample (which, if you replace in your code `"5%"` with `.05` does work IF you had an actual form in your question with those values and properly got the values from it as your function does IF you fix the parenthesis) i.e.
`console.log(((((25000) + (25000) * .05)) / 10) / 12);` logs `218.75` -note this does NOT match your examples above or the example in comments.  Clarity of question counts

Answer (score 1):

You can write your `5%` as `0.05` and then you can do the calculations with this value.

So assign to DAE not the string `"5%"`
Assign to it the value 0.05

```
let DAE = 0.05;
```